# howto make a delay and how to start a function only in debug mode in c#?

Tags: c#

I have two questions:

1. How to make a delay in C#, I want to call a function after x Seconds when the program start, but the other things in the program should go on
2. is it possible to call a function or a statement only when the program runs in debug mode?

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at once.

Answer (score 3):

For #1 You need a `Timer`, that you start when the program starts and set it to tick at x seconds. You register for the `Tick` event of the timer that will be fired and there you call the method you want. **Important:** in the handler of the Tick event, before calling your method, you need to stop the timer. Otherwise it will keep calling your method at x seconds interval.

Here is a [comparison between the different timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) available in .NET.

For #2 You could use compilation directives:

```
#if DEBUG

CallMyMethod();

#endif
```

You can also use the [Conditional Attribute.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx)

```
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public void CallMyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This method will be called only when in DEBUG mode.");
        // notice the "DEBUG" string in the attribute parameter
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1)Start a function in a separate thread and include Thread.Sleep() in that function.

2)Use #if DEBUG

```
#if DEBUG
MyMethod();
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody gave this yet..

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    //code to run when under debug
}
```

Comment: If execution speed is important then #if DEBUG is a better solution because anything inside the #if won't even be compiled when released.  Your proposal will run the if statement even in release mode.  It's probably not a significant amount of processing, but...

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: can be solved by create a thread and having that thread sleep for x number of seconds then execute its code.

A small EX

```
static void Thread1()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("hi");

 }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Threading.Thread T = new System.Threading.Thread(Thread1);
    T.Start();
    while (T.IsAlive)
    {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
          Console.WriteLine("Waiting");

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");

}
```

question 2: you can use [`#if`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For 2) note that if you want to run the program in debug mode without the function you can undefine the DEBUG by adding `#undef DEBUG` at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

For the first option maybe the easiest way is the use of the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) in combination with Thread.Sleep.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
  Thread.Sleep(numMilliseconds);
  // Your code here
});
```

Though if you block the thread for some time timers are probably a better solution.